# Adding a custom field to the default user model - if extending it, should I do migrations?

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to extend the user model with a XP field. After writing the code (which I think it is right) I decided to try it out.

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

```
ProgrammingError at /register/
relation "accounts_userprofile" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "accounts_userprofile" ("user_id", "xp") VALUES ...
                 ^
```

I think this is happening because I extended the user model but I didn't run the migrations.
Here's my code:
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth
from .models import UserProfile

# Create your views here.
def login(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
        username = req.POST['username']
        password = req.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(req, user)
            messages.success(req, 'Acum eşti logat')
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            messages.error(req, 'Numele de utilizator sau parola sunt greşite')
            return redirect('login')
        return
    else:
        return render(req, "../templates/pagini/login.html")
def register(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
        first_name = req.POST['first_name']
        last_name = req.POST['last_name']
        username = req.POST['username']
        email = req.POST['email']
        password = req.POST['password']
        password2 = req.POST['password2']

        if password == password2:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.error(req, 'Numele de utilizator deja există')
                return redirect('register')
            else:
                if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    messages.error(req, 'E-mailul este deja folosit')
                    return redirect('register')
                else:
                    user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
                    user.UserProfile.xp = 0
                    user.save()
                    messages.success(req, 'Acum eşti logat')
                    return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(req, 'Parolele diferă')
            return redirect('register')
    else:
        return render(req, "../templates/pagini/register.html")
def dashboard(req):
    return render(req, "../templates/pagini/dashboard.html")
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    xp = models.IntegerField(default=0)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

When I run python manage.py showmigrations I can't see any migration for this app - which is an app created by me by the name of 'accounts'.

I think I'm missing something because when I had another model I did a migration, but it didn't work as expected. Now I can't see any migration for this app, even if I deleted the migrations folder from it.

So is the error coming from not running 'migrate'? If yes, how should I run it because I can't see any migrations for it.

Thanks.

Comment: run `python manage.py makemigrations` first

Comment: @JibinMathews I'm getting 'no changes detected'

Comment: do python manage.py makemigrations <myapp> where <myapp> is the name of your app [accounts]

Comment: Now it worked. Thanks. If you want you can add this as an answer so I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

`python manage.py makemigrations <myapp>` where  is the name of your app,
   this will make django detect changes to your model

`python manage.py migrate` commit the changes to database